# when selecting second dropdown ng-model object return null

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angularjs, typescript

When I making dropdown selection, my ng-model object becomes null, not sure why.

Because it returns null I getting below error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')
```

My code

```
<select ng-options="option.name for option in $ctrl.getAvailableColumnOptions()" ng-model="$ctrl.secondColumnOption"></select>
<select ng-options="option.name for option in $ctrl.getAvailableColumnOptions()" ng-model="$ctrl.thirdColumnOption"> </select>


getAvailableColumnOptions(){
      return this.allAvailableColumnOptions.filter(x => x.name !== this.secondColumnOption.name && x.name !== this.thirdColumnOption.name && x.name !== this.fourthColumnOption.name);
}
```

Comment: Just trying to understand your business requirements. Are you trying to make sure that each selection can only be selected once? Something like you might see when selecting security questions for an account?

Comment: Here's a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-bwjsrb?file=home/home.html) doing something very similar. Notably, the `getAvailableQuestions` function, which is similar to your `getAvailableColumnOptions`, is very clean.

Comment: Jacob, this is great. it almost what I was trying to accomplish. Issue from allSecurityQuestions array, first 3 is default selected by first 3 options and now dropdown shows remaining allSecurityQuestions of array. When option is changed (something else selected from dropdown) previously default selected will be added back to allSecurityQuestions and selected will be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because after selection `getAvailableColumnOptions()` will be fired. And there you are filtering datasource to exclude selected options. So now dropdown doesn't have an appropriate model in the datasource and `ng-model` will be cleared.

**UPD:**

```
<select ng-options="option.name for option in $ctrl.getAvailableColumnOptions('secondColumnOption')" ng-model="$ctrl.secondColumnOption"></select>
<select ng-options="option.name for option in $ctrl.getAvailableColumnOptions('thirdColumnOption')" ng-model="$ctrl.thirdColumnOption"> </select>


getAvailableColumnOptions(ignoreOption) {
  return this.allAvailableColumnOptions
    .filter(x => (ignoreOption === 'secondColumnOption' || x.name !== this.secondColumnOption.name)
      && (ignoreOption === 'thirdColumnOption' || x.name !== this.thirdColumnOption.name)
      && (ignoreOption === 'fourthColumnOption' || x.name !== this.fourthColumnOption.name)
    );
}
```

Comment: But I do have "secondColumnOption" and etc. hard coded. You probably see why I am trying to exclude. Whenever dropdown option is selected, I don't want other dropdown options have that in the list, since its been selected somewhere else. Not sure how I can achieve this.

Comment: Updated answer with code. I guess you want something like that.

Comment: this is what I was looking for. Earlier I solved this issue with using simple array of string using <option> and ng-repeat,  instead of array of objects. But this is much better for me. Only problem now, with this solution, not sure how to set default selected for each option and those option not to show on each dropdown on initial load

Comment: you can just set default value as simple as `this.secondColumnOption = this.allAvailableColumnOptions[0];`